# convert a C# datetime object into Excel date format

Tags: c#, excel, csv, datetime

I need to convert a C# datetime object into the dreaded Excel date format:
https://datapub.cdlib.org/2014/04/10/abandon-all-hope-ye-who-enter-dates-in-excel/

i.e. number of days since 1 Jan 1900 expressed as a floating point number.

Is there any way to do it without resorting to DIY code?
I need it in order to create Excel-friendly CSV exports

Googling around I didn't find anything useful except that good blog post

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the CSV as yyyy-MM-dd? It might just work.

Comment: CSV is not the same as Excel. And the Excel date is well defined, there is no format to dread if you know how dates are actually stored. This used to be common knowledge once

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your quick response. Most user will click on the CSV and they will open the file using Excel. So the timestamps have to be formatted as "OLE Automation Data" (aka the Excel floating point number representing a date). I understand perfectly that CSV is just text, no "column type" is carried alongside the column

Comment: A CSV is a text file. An Excel file is a zipped xml file. When you click on a `csv` Excel **imports** the text file using the current user locale's settings and defaults. You asked about storing a date in Excel though, not how to import CSV data into Excel. PS The linked article has more to do with R's discrepancies and misunderstanding Excel.

Comment: If you want an unambiguous text format for dates, use the ISO8601 format *only*,  eg  `2016-10-21T13:45`. Excel detects that this isn't a localized date format. Anything else is actually a localized format that may fail.

Comment: Another option is to use a package or library that generates actual xlsx files instead of CSVs, eg EPPlus. Creating a sheet is as easy as `sheet.LoadFromCollection(someList)`

Comment: cool thanks, even knowing the actual name of the format "OLE Automation date" has unlocked a lot of useful stuff from Google

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Excel dates use the OLE Automation date format. You can retrieve it with [DateTime.ToOADate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx)

OA Dates are a double whose integer part is the date offset from 30 December 1899 (ie earlier dates are negative) and fractional part is the time divided by 24.

This type was used a lot in the COM/VB6 days. Nowadays it's needed for Excel and when you need to call COM APIs that expect dates or variants with a date content.

Answer (score 4):

You can use following method to convert from Excel Date back to C# DateTime

```
return DateTime.FromOADate(SerialDate);
```